How should I wire a ceiling fan remote where two switches are used to control the fixture and still use the remote to control speed?
I want to preface that I have reviewed the previous questions for this item. I have a Harbor Breeze Bristle ceiling fan (Model #AR13-44blk) [Item #5497066].
I have 2 wall switches. 4 wires coming out of ceiling (black-hot, red-hot, white-common, bare- ground), a ceiling fan and a remote. How do I wire them and still be able to use wall switches?
For additional reference, the remote has a black and a white from the top and a black, blue, and white from the bottom. There is also a yellow wire labelled Antennae and do not cut.
I have tried wiring per the diagram instructions (match colors no three wires other than ground). Currently, I can get both the light and the fan to turn on by connecting:

All three grounds,
Blue fan wire to red ceiling wire,
Receiver input white, ceiling white and fan white together.
Ceiling black, Receiver input black, fan black together.

The problem is the remote does not seem to adjust the fan speed. When I rewire:

All three grounds together
Blue fan wire to red ceiling wire
Receiver input white to ceiling white
Receiver output white to fan white
Receiver input black to ceiling black
Receiver output black to fan black

The light still works, but no luck on the fan. Additionally, a voltage test indicates that of the receiver output wires, only the blue wire labelled lights and yellow wire labelled antennae are hot. The receiver input black is hot, but the receiver output is not. Again, the remote does not turn the fan on or do much of anything.
A picture of the wiring minus the four ceiling wires for reference:


Is this picture of the wiring from the fan instructions? You could add a switch as the answer below suggests. Or you could leave your two switches in the positions they are in that provide power to the fan and leave them alone from now on. If you wired it as the instructions show and it does not work, it is not out of the question that it is just broke from the factory. Return it and try another one.

These are incompatible methods.
The typical attached to the fan remote is designed for replacing a light with a fan/light without having to run a new cable. It actually works best with no switch at all, or more commonly a piece of tape over the switch.
The solution is to bypass the remote and replace the simple switches with a hardwired fan speed control/light dimmer switch. Something like this Lutron from Home Depot:

